# Can I trap the "Cannot truncate table" error and Delete instead?

Tags: sql-server, sql-delete, truncate

I know that a valid replacement for `TRUNCATE TABLE "MyTable"` is:
`DELETE FROM MyTable
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('DATABASENAME.dbo.MyTable',RESEED, 0)`

However, I'd prefer to use `TRUNCATE TABLE` whenever possible, but I have a few clients who use database replication.  For those clients, I get the error: `Cannot truncate table 'MyTable' because it is published for replication or enabled for Change Data Capture.`

Is there a way to either 1) pre-test that `TRUNCATE` will work, or 2) issue the `TRUNCATE` command in such a way that it does not fail, but instead leaves a testable value (`@@ERROR` maybe?) that allows me to execute the `DELETE` if it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
begin try
    truncata table dbo.YourTableName;
end try
begin catch
    delete from dbo.YourTableName;
end catch
```

Something like this...

Comment: your idea, with a couple of minor tweaks, works fine under SQL Server 2012:
`begin try
    TRUNCATE TABLE "MyTable"
end try
begin catch
    DELETE FROM MyTable;
 DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.MyTable',RESEED, 0)
end catch`
...this works